# How to extract expression matching an email address in a text file using R or Command Line?

Tags: regex, r, terminal, command

I have a text file that contains email addresses and some information.

I would like to know how can I extract those email address using R or the terminal?

I've read that I can used some regular expression that would match an email address such as

```
"^[_a-z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,4})$"
```

But what command or function shall I used to extract those emails?

There are no pattern in the text file. The command or function should just do a search on the document and extract the email addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets take an unstructured example file:

```
this is a test

fred is fred@foo.com and joe is joe@example.com - but
 @this is a twitter handle for twit@here.com
```

Then if you do:

```
myText <- readLines("testmail.txt")
emails = unlist(regmatches(myText, gregexpr("([_a-z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,4}))", myText)))
> emails
[1] "fred@foo.com"    "joe@example.com" "twit@here.com"
```

it extracts a vector of all the emails, including when there's more than one on a line. I don't think it will find email addresses broken over line breaks, but if you paste the read lines together it might do that too:

```
> myText = paste(readLines("testmail.txt"),collapse=" ")
> emails = regmatches(myText, gregexpr("([_a-z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,4}))", myText))
> emails
[[1]]
[1] "fred@foo.com"    "joe@example.com" "twit@here.com"
```

In this case there's only one line in `myText` because we pasted all the lines together, so there's only one element in the returned list `emails` object.

Note that regex string isn't a strict definition of a valid email address. For example, it limits itself to addresses that are between 2 and 4 characters after the last dot. So it doesn't match `fred@foo.fnord`. There are top level domains that are longer than four characters so you may need to modify the regex.

Also, it only matches alphanumeric and dot in the name part - so valid addresses such as `foo+bar@google.com` won't match.

A regex that fixes these two issues might be:

```
 "([_+a-z0-9-]+(\\.[_+a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,14}))"
```

but it probably has other issues and you'd be better of searching for a better email address regex online. I say better, because a perfect one doesn't exist...

Comment: @Spacedmn should the `2,14` on the second regex be `2,4`?

Comment: @TylerRinker, actually it should be `{2,63}`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Domain_name_syntax,_internationalization

Answer (score 1):

This can also work :

```
 aa <- paste(readLines("C:\\MY_FOLDER\\NOI\\file1sample.txt"),collapse = " ")
 temp <- sapply(str_extract_all(aa,"[a-z_+0-9]+\\@\\w+\\.[a-z]{2,4}"), function(x){ paste(x,collapse = " ")})
```

Answer (score 0):

Read your file into R and use `grep`.

```
myText <- readLines("your.file")
Emails <- grep("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,4})$", myText, value=T)
```

This will return the whole line that the email appears on, if there is other information on that line you will need to split it up first using something like `strsplit`

Comment: Only if the line contains nothing but an email because you anchored your regex with ^ and $.