# Email Extraction in R

Tags: regex, r, email

I am trying to extract all the email id from description.

```
> string <- c("From : William KWANG (TLA) To : Melissa_FOO@nba.gov.sd,feedback@tla.gov.sd,Milly_YUEN@tla.gov.sd,Faridah_B_SALLEH@tla.gov.sd,
+ Muhamad_Rosli_MOKTAR@tla.gov.sd cc : Juzaidi_LASA@nba.gov.sd,Kamis_TAHIR@nba.gov.sd,TAN_Xiao_Wei@nba.gov.sd Bcc : Sent On : Wed Mar 04 16:46:29 SGT 2015")

> str_extract_all(string=string,pattern="\\b[-A-Za-z0-9_.%]+\\@[-A-Za-z0-9_.%]+\\.[A-Za-z]+ ")
[[1]]
[1] "Muhamad_Rosli_MOKTAR@tla.gov.sd " "TAN_Xiao_Wei@nba.gov.sd "
```

However i am not able to extract all the email ids.

My question is, there are alist of emails mentioned in to: list with comma, but the query fetches the last result.

Comment: Maybe you should anonymize the email address, no?

Comment: This might answer your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076575/how-to-extract-expression-matching-an-email-address-in-a-text-file-using-r-or-co

Comment: I tried the suggested ones, before posting but i am not getting the desired result

Comment: @stribizhev this question sligtly deviates from the other questions asked. My question is, there are alist of emails mentioned in to: list with comma, but the query fetches the last result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trailing space in your regex is the problem. The only addresses matching that condition are `Muhamad_Rosli_MOKTAR@tla.gov.sd` `TAN_Xiao_Wei@nba.gov.sd` because they're the only ones with tailing spaces. So just remove it:

```
string <- c("From : William KWANG (TLA) To : Melissa_FOO@nba.gov.sd,feedback@tla.gov.sd,Milly_YUEN@tla.gov.sd,Faridah_B_SALLEH@tla.gov.sd,Muhamad_Rosli_MOKTAR@tla.gov.sd cc : Juzaidi_LASA@nba.gov.sd,Kamis_TAHIR@nba.gov.sd,TAN_Xiao_Wei@nba.gov.sd Bcc : Sent On : Wed Mar 04 16:46:29 SGT 2015")
str_extract_all(string=string,pattern="\\b[-A-Za-z0-9_.%]+\\@[-A-Za-z0-9_.%]+\\.[A-Za-z]+")

[[1]]
[1] "Melissa_FOO@nba.gov.sd"          "feedback@tla.gov.sd"             "Milly_YUEN@tla.gov.sd"           "Faridah_B_SALLEH@tla.gov.sd"    
[5] "Muhamad_Rosli_MOKTAR@tla.gov.sd" "Juzaidi_LASA@nba.gov.sd"         "Kamis_TAHIR@nba.gov.sd"          "TAN_Xiao_Wei@nba.gov.sd"
```

Note this might work for whatever you're doing here, but email addresses are notoriously difficult to interpret with regular expressions, so don't expect this method to work for every address you might come across.