# Filter operation with for loop in R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I want to apply the code below to 21 csv files and put them in the data frame like in this question, one after another as **data.frame**; [add one column below another in a data.frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40830832/add-one-column-below-another-in-a-data-frame-in-r)
How can I apply this like a loop? any suggestions??

```
H1 <- csv_group %>%
  select(Group.1, harvest, crop,plot, chm_H1)%>%
  filter(harvest==1)
```

Comment: possible approach: load file in a list using `list.files()`, and perform read operario with something line `mylist <- lapply( myfiles, data.table::fread, ...)`, and then rowbind the list to one data.table, with something like `data.table::rbindlist( mylist, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a for loop with a small amount of setup before hand:

```r
path_to_files = "c:/folder/subfolder"
list_of_files_to_read = c("file1.csv", "file2.csv", ...)

output = data.frame()

# loop through files
for(file in list_of_files_to_read){
  # load each file
  this_file_full_path = paste0(path_to_files,"/",file)
  this_file_contents = read.csv(this_file_full_path)

  # filter as required
  prepared_df = this_file_contents %>%
      select(Group.1, harvest, crop,plot, chm_H1)%>%
      filter(harvest==1)

  # append to output
  output = rbind(output, prepared_df)
}
```