# Extract specific emails from different emails in a column- R

Tags: r, email, text-extraction

I want to extract specific emails (@enron.com) from 'To' column in my dataframe.In some of the rows there are more than one email. For example in one row I have this : `mark.guzman@enron.com, creightonca@hotmail.com, brendanf@gfsloans.com, seastape@teleport.com, penn_eric@salkeiz.k12.or.us,joe.stepenovitch@enron.com, jan.king@enron.com`. My question is how can I extract just Enron domain (@enron.com) emails from this column and save it in new column?I can extract them but the problem is it puts each email in a row that is not true because for example if a row contains 10 Enron emails out of 20 emails I want to have all that Enron emails in one row not in 10 rows.I run the code from here: [How to extract expression matching an email address in a text file using R or Command Line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076575/how-to-extract-expression-matching-an-email-address-in-a-text-file-using-r-or-co) , `emails = regmatches(df, gregexpr("([_a-z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@enron.com)", df))`but I get this error : `Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 2, 0, 5`.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your input data and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` for this

```
subset(df, grepl("enron.com", To))
```

If there are multiple emails in a single row, use the `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
data.frame(To =sapply(str_extract_all(df$To, "\\S+@enron.com"), paste, collapse=","))
```